# How to slice and mondify a mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and I am trying to project the `amount` field from a `decimal` to a `double` when queried. Right now I add `$$ROOT` to an array and then slice that array to just get a subset of transactions. I figure I can probably convert it when I push to the array (`$group` stage) or after slicing (`$project` stage) but I can't figure out how. Any tips? End goal is to present the sum, count, and most recent transactions (I need to add sorting logic later).

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {$match:{}},
    {$group:{
        _id:null,
        transactions:{
            $push:"$$ROOT"
        },
        count:{$sum: 1},
        sum: {$sum: "$amount"}
    }},
    {$project:{
        _id:0,
        summary:{ count: "$count", sum: {$convert:{input:"$sum",to:"double"}}},
        transactions: {$slice:["$transactions", 2]}
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) allow me to do this:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([{
    $facet:{
        summary: [
            {$match:{}},
            {$group:{
                _id:null,
                count:{$sum: 1},
                sum: {$sum: "$amount"}
            }},
            {$project:{
                _id:0,
                count: "$count",
                sum: {$convert:{input:"$sum",to:"double"}}}
            }
        ],
        transactions: [
            {$match:{}},
            {$sort:{date:-1,timestamp:-1}},
            {$limit:1},
            {$addFields:{amount: {$convert:{input:"$amount",to:"double"}}}}
        ]
    }
}]);
```